# Why Does a .dll file allow programs to be modularized?

Tags: dll

Excerpt From Micrsoft's "What is a .dll?":

> "By using a DLL, a program can be modularized into separate
>   components. For example, an accounting program may be sold by module.
>   Each module can be loaded into the main program at run time if that
>   module is installed. Because the modules are separate, the load time
>   of the program is faster, and a module is only loaded when that
>   functionality is requested. Additionally, updates are easier to apply
>   to each module without affecting other parts of the program. For
>   example, you may have a payroll program, and the tax rates change each
>   year. When these changes are isolated to a DLL, you can apply an
>   update without needing to build or install the whole program again."

Ref:http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815065

DLL's are:
loaded at runtime
can "dynamically loaded" (by multiple programs at the same time)
 - which allows saving of resources
 - lowers disk space requirements

But why do they promote "modulizing" programs?
What would happen if there weren't .dll files?
Could someone provide/expand on the example

Comment: It's just an example. Use your imagination!

Comment: I don't get it. Why do .dll promote modulization? I really tried but I mean... couldn't you do it anyway? You have the main program, if it finds the module, load it in...and that is it.

Comment: And just where would it find this module?

Comment: Okay, so lets say its the accounting software. Main program installs in c:/accounting, and the modules are installed in c:/accounting/modules/?

Comment: Ah... wait a minute... the module themselves are .dll files... right? Okay... I'm...sorry. I get it. The answer I checked helped me realize this, heh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modular programs provide a way of making a particular functionality available to many programs without having to include the same code in all of them. Also, they allow greater compatibility between programs since they would essentially use the same methods in common DLLs to obtain the same results.

One would write a program in a modular fashion such that different parts of the program could be maintained separately. Say you had some clever way of reading and writing your own data format to files. Say you make improvements to that technique. If the code for reading and writing the files lived in a DLL, you would only need to update the DLL. The program itself would remain unchanged.

Comment: What is the alternative to using .dll files?

Comment: DLL is one means of making a "library" that is specific to Windows binaries. There are different techniques in different platforms, but all are very similar. The alternative to a library is to include the code in the program itself. When you do this, it is not reusable though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one monolithic EXE, you have to

- pay for all the extra time relinking it, even if 1 source file changed (this is painful if it's > 80 MB, as is the case in large projects),
- ship the entire EXE, when you could only ship a single DLL which is a fraction of the size (for patches/updates).

Breaking it up into DLLs you

- have pluggability: The EXE is the host application and others can write DLLs that "plug into" the host via a well-defined interface. DLLs can be interchanged as long as they conform to the interface.
- can share code across other DLLs and EXEs.
- can have some DLLs be optionally loaded on demand, only if they're used, and unloaded when they're not needed
- similar to above, have optional functionality. With a single EXE you have to download *everything*, even if some components are rarely used. With DLLs, you could have a system that downloads and installs features as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest advantage of dlls is probably during development of the original program. Without dlls you wouldn't be able to integrate with existing libraries without including the original source code. By including an existing library as a dll you don't need the source since it's all encapsulated in the dll. It would be a nightmare to develop in frameworks like .Net without dlls since you constantly include other libraries...

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to breaking your program down in `n > 1` pieces is to keep it in `n == 1` piece.  Why is this bad?  Well it isn't always bad (maybe the BIOS is a good example?).  But for user programs it usually is.  Why?  First we need to define what a program is.

**What is a program?**

A *simple* "program", roughly speaking, consists of an entry point (i.e. offset to the main function), functions and global variables.  A function consists of instructions and information about what local variables are needed to run the function.  To be executed a program must be loaded in primary memory/RAM (the aforementioned information).  Because our program has functions (and not just jump statements), that implies the existence of a stack, which implies the existence of a containing environment managing the stack.  (I suppose you could have a program that manages its own stack but I'd argue then your program is not a program anymore but an environment.)  This environment contains the program, starts in the entry point and executes each instruction, be it "go to this part of the RAM and add it to whatever is in this register" or "If this register is all 0 then jump ahead this many instructions and resume execution there" indefinitely or until the program gives control back to its environment.  (This is somewhat simplified - context switches in multi-process environments, illegal memory access, illegal instructions, etc. can also cause control to be taken from the program.)

Anyway, so we have two options: either load the entire program at once or have it stored and loaded in pieces.

**n == 1**

There are some advantages to doing it all at once:

- Once the program is in memory no disk access is required to execute further (unless the program explicitly asks there to be).
- Since the program is compiled/linked before execution begins you can do everything without any sort of string names/comparisons - go directly to the address (or an offset).
- Functions are never out of sync with one another.

**n > 1**

There are some disadvantages, though, which mirror the advantages:

- Most programs don't execute all code paths most of the time.  I think there's some studies that in most programs most of the time spent executing is spent in a fraction of the instructions present in the program.  In other words something like 20% of the program is executed 80% of the time (I just made that particular figure up - but you get the idea).  If we divide our program up enough and only load instruction sets (i.e. functions) as they are needed then we won't waste time loading the 80% we'll never use this execution of the program.  Along these lines we can ultimately fit more concurrently executing programs in our RAM at once if we only end up loading the fraction of the program we need.
- Most programs share similar functions (i.e. storing data/trees/hashes/sorting/etc., reading input, writing output, etc.) and if each program has its own local copy then you can't reuse instruction code.
- Many programs depend on the existence of others and are maintained by separate companies/groups/individuals.  By releasing versioned modules we don't have to synchronize releases all the time.

**Conclusion**

These aren't the only points to consider but the first ones that came to my mind.  I'd recommend reading about compilers, linkers and operating systems.  That will answer this question more thoroughly than I and other questions I'm sure this has brought up.  To recap dll's aren't the "best" way of packaging executable programs in all situations and circumstances - they have a particular use and advantages and disadvantages.